# How to get rid of the Fogger lens?

Tags: unity, lenses

though I prefer using Fogger instead of creating web-apps in chrome, I don't need the Fogger lens in my Unity Dash. The few web-apps I have are easily found via global search or applications lens.

I tried `sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-fogger` and some variations, but had no success.
Can anyone tell me under what name the Fogger lens can be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try deleting/moving/renaming the fogger-lens file, but be sure to make a backup. Then log out and log back in.

The fogger-lens file can be found here: `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/fogger/bin/`.